# Can't exec 'coremlc' (No such file or directory) for Xcode 10 Beta 6

Tags: ios, macos, coreml, coremltools, macos-mojave

I am trying to run some projects that use CoreML models in XCode 10 Beta 6 and I am using macOS Mojave Version 10.14 (18A384a). I can't build/run any of the demo projects or even the projects provided by Apple. The models cannot be compiled and I get the error "can't exec 'coremlc' (No such file or directory)". Any idea how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

I did not change anything but unzipped the Xcode bundle again and it worked. I don't know exactly what caused the error.